# Does Enterprise support tokenisation?

Tags: realex-payments-api

Does Realex support tokenisation of credit card details, like SagePay does? We're looking at integrating it into a Magento module as most of the ones on the market are lacking

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. Yes, Realex Payments offer a Card Storage solution (we used to refer to it as RealVault). The card details are securely stored on our side and we just return the token reference to the Magento backend. Our official Magento plugin supports this out of the box and is available on Connect:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/realex-payments-plugin-for-magento-community-enterprise-2.html

We also have a detailed user guide available [here](http://www.realexpayments.com/images/Magento_Realex_Configuration_Guide_V1.1.pdf).

Best,

Seán